# transferring large mail archive from mac osx to linux

Tags: macos, debian, email, imap, migration

I have a 50GB email archive on my apple laptop, stored locally, in whatever format the Mail application uses.

I'm switching over to a desktop debian machine and want to transfer this archive without losing anything, and without changing any timestamps or receive dates on the messages.

How can I do this?

- use imapsync?
- set up an IMAP server on my debian machine and drag and drop the mail folders from inside Mail to the debian server?
- copy over the mail folders or files from my user directory on my apple laptop?

I want to make sure the transfer doesn't stop halfway, resulting in duplicate messages if I try it again.

Comment: Knowing the format the messages are currently stored in would be helpful.

Comment: Thunderbird mail client uses a format that is easily transferred, check whether you can import your archive in it. `Menu:Tools>Import>...`

Answer (score 1):

The IMAP-on-debian route would probably be the easiest.

If you don't want to set up an IMAP server on you own, your mail provider probably already has the capability.  If they do, you'd just connect via IMAP to them using the OSX Mail Application, and then set up your new mail client on debian to connect as well.

Then just drag/drop the messages back up to the server from OSX and once that's done, copy them back down on the debian side.  At 50GB, this will take a lot of time, but would require the least amount of configuration on your side.

The OSX mail application, as expected from Apple, stores mail in a non-standard format.  There are ways to simply convert and copy the files, sparing you some IMAP work, but possibly a bit more complex than you're prepared for.  Check out this link (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55084/what-format-does-apple-mail-store-its-emails-in) for some hints.